# Formula to input number and letters separated by "-"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel document in which I control the Office's licenses in my enterprise. I want to edit the cells to automatically add the "-", just how it appears in the product key. Remembering that these keys follows the example XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX, there are numbers and letters in every group of five characters. What's the code to format the cells in this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have OFFICE 365 Excel you can use an Array version of TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",,MID(A1,(ROW(1:5)-1)*5+1,5))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

If you do not then a simple parsing of the value and concatenation:

```
=LEFT(A1,5) & "-" & MID(A1,6,5) & "-" & MID(A1,11,5) & "-" & MID(A1,16,5 )& "-" & MID(A1,21,5)
```

Comment: Please, take a look at the "answer" that I've posted and see if you can help me, thanks!!

Comment: @Ferreira you can't do that with a number format. It will need to be vba or a formula. There is no format that will do this in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 =CONCATENATE(MID(A1,1,5),"-",MID(A1,6,5),"-",MID(A1,11,5),"-",MID(A1,16,5),"-",MID(A1,21,5))
```

It's a standard formula that works on any Excel version.

Comment: Please, take a look at the "answer" that I've posted and see if you can help me, thanks!!Please, take a look at the "answer" that I've posted and see if you can help me, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to enter the product key into a cell and have that same cell add the dashes by using cell formatting.  If you use a formula, the formula would have to be in a separate cell.  If you want the cell you enter the key in to automatically update, you can use VBA to do it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim strOrig As String, strNew As String

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Len(Target.Value) = 25 Then
            strOrig = Target.Value
            strNew = Left(strOrig, 5) & "-" & Mid(strOrig, 6, 5) & "-" & Mid(strOrig, 11, 5) & "-" & Mid(strOrig, 16, 5) & "-" & Right(strOrig, 5)
            Target.Value = strNew
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Place this code in the sheet you have your data on.  This code assumes the product keys are in column A.  If they are in a different column change Target.column = 1 to the appropriate column number.